# Is there a way to hide chars on start point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The "$$$" chars were used for get indexof and hide list in code behind. Now I want to ask is there a way to hide these chars with jQuery and/or JavaScript?

```
$$$<ul id = "myid"class = "listbranch">
       <li>Битола</li>
       <li>Скопје</li>
       <li>Охрид</li>
       <li>Прилеп</li>
       <li>Ресен</li>
       <li>Гостивар</li>
       <li>Куманово</li>
       <li>Гевгелија</li>
       <li>Штип</li>
       <li>Велес</li>
       <li>Пробиштип</li>
       <li>Тетово</li>
       <li>Кочани</li>
       <li>Валандово</li>
       <li>Струмица</li>
       <li>Крива Паланка</li>
       <li>Кавадарци</li>
       <li>Неготино</li>
       </ul>$$$
```

Comment: While I don't quite understand the question, it sure smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put them in an element like `<span class="hide">$$$</span>` and then use JQuery to hide the element using the following,

```
//hide the element with the hide class
$(".hide").hide();
```

Another soution is to wrap the $$$ in a span tag and hide them using css as suggested by user5295483 comment. However I would suggest using a class name just in case you don't want to hide all of your span tags.

HTML:

```
<span>$$$</span>
```

CSS:

```
 span{
       display:"none";
 }

  /* use this class if you don't want to hide all span tags*/
 .hide{

     display:"none";

 }
```

If you want hide the $$$ using plain JavaScript? You can try the following:

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/WwxEGV)

```
    //Call the hide function,
    //the $ must be escaped so that regexp will pick up all three of them
    hide(/\$\$\$/);

    function hide(text) {//begin function

     //create a new RegExp object with the global replacement flag
     var search = new RegExp(text,"g");        


    //wrap the $$$ with a span element
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(search, "<span class='hide'>$$$$$$</span>");


    //store the collection of elements with the hide class
    var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

    //loop through the collection
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {//begin for loop

        //hide the element
        collection[i].style.display = "none";

    }//end for loop

}//end function
```

Comment: thats a good solution, but how to get the $$$ into an element automatically? Maybe also with js

Comment: I use span and set css property to display none. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user5295483 I added a suggestion in my solution that might help you in the future should you decide to have more span tags on your page that do not contain the $$$ string.

Comment: @zypro I added a  plain JavaScript solution to my solution, if you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't publish the file with '$$$' in it in the first place. Strip them out during the build process:

```
sed -ie 's/\$\$\$//g' out.html
```

Boom, problem solved. If you must keep the '$$$' in the file for some reason you can still pre-process the file:

```
sed -ie 's?\$\$\$?<span class="ns-hide">$$$</span>/?g' out.html
```

Good luck!